# displaying value from db to dropdown

Tags: php

I have a table which is list of topics and I used select to display all topics in a drop down list.
here is my code:

```
    <select id="iask_topic" name="iask_topic" class="form-control">
    <?php 
    $database = new Database();
    $conn = $database->getConnection();
    $db = new Priest($conn);
    $res = $db->topic();
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option>'.$value['topic_list'].'</option>';
    ?>
    </select>

   <?php
    }
   ?>
```

But what happened is that: after displaying only one topic reside inside the dropdown and the other topics are outside the dropdown ..

here is the sample screen shot of what exactly happened after displaying the topics on a dropdown

[image]

Comment: foreach loop closing bracket missing

Comment: Move the select closing tag `</select>` to outside/after the loop `foreach ($res as $key => $value) { ... } </select>`.

Comment: and also print_r($res) to check fetch data

Comment: oh sorry i didn't include the close bracket but it has a close bracket below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

close foreach bracket: }

```
<select id="iask_topic" name="iask_topic" class="form-control">
<?php 
  $database = new Database();
  $conn = $database->getConnection();
  $db = new Priest($conn);
  $res = $db->topic();

  foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
   echo '<option>'.$value['topic_list'].'</option>'; } // <--- Here --
?>
</select>
```

Comment: ohh isee cause what i did was put the close bracket outside cause i have another html tag below..</select> and i forgot to remove those thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this:

```
<?php 
$database = new Database();
$conn = $database->getConnection();
$db = new Priest($conn);
$res = $db->topic();
?>

<select id="iask_topic" name="iask_topic" class="form-control">

<?php 
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
   echo '<option>'.$value['topic_list'].'</option>';
}
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your foreach loop

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
echo '<option>'.$value['topic_list'].'</option>';
}
```